# How do I test that my print function was called, in my other function?

Tags: python, pytest

I have 2 functions here:

```
def f1(x):
    f2(x+3)
    return x * x


def f2(y):
    print("some statement")
```

I have my test here:

```
def test_f1(mocker):
    mocker.patch("functions.f2")
    assert f1(1) == 1
```

I want to test that `f2` is called, with the expected value but without printing the print statement. I tried doing this:

```
 def test_f1(mocker):
        mocker.patch("functions.f2")
        assert f1(1) == 1
        assert f2(1) == None
```

But this isn't a valuable test because it says nothing about the underlying code.

Also, I am getting an error here when I want to assert my mock was called:

```
def test_f1(mocker):
    mock = mocker
    mock.f2 = f2
    assert f1(1) == 1
    mock.f2.assert_called_once()
```

It's saying the function `f2` has no attribute `assert_called_once`

```
>       mock.f2.assert_called_once()
E       AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called_once'
```

Comment: Are you able to change the code within the f2() function, or do you strictly need it to remain as it is-- printing something?

I figure you do not need to keep it as such -- in that case you could have a global variable that starts as false and then you set it to true ONLY when f2 is called. This is a hackey way to do it but would work.

Alternatively you could use a counter, define it *outside* of f2(), and then whenever you call f2(), increment the value by 1. 

In your tests you could do:

assert MY_COUNTER == 1

where the '1' here represents how many times you expext to call f2

Answer (score 1):

```
MY_TEST_COUNTER = 0

def f1(x):
    f2(x+3)
    return x * x


def f2(y):
    MY_TEST_COUNTER += 1
    print("some statement")

def test_f1(mocker):
       mocker.patch("functions.f2")
       assert f1(1) == 1
       assert MY_TEST_COUNTER == 1
```

This would test that the function is called, but I'm not certain fi you are checking if its being called at all or if the parameter passed in is the correct one.

EDIT:
After reading again it seems you are also looking for the correct parameter being passed in.. This is another hackey way to go about doing it but I believe it would work:

```
MY_TEST_COUNTER = 0
PARAM_VALUE = None

def f1(x):
    f2(x+3)
    return x * x


def f2(y):
    MY_TEST_COUNTER += 1
    PARAM_VALUE = y
    print("some statement")

def test_f1(mocker):
    mocker.patch("functions.f2")
    assert f1(1) == 1
    assert MY_TEST_COUNTER == 1
    assert PARAM_VALUE == 4
```